# How do I send emails with Arabic content via PHP's mail function?

Tags: php, email, arabic

I'm having a challenge with sending emails with arabic content using PHP's mail function. Let's say I have this simple arabic string:

بريد

I've tried several ways to utilize the headers, but the emails content all still end up with something like: `X*X1X(X1Y X/`. However, the email subject is correctly encoded if I use arabic characters (thanks to the base64_encode, see function below)

Here's one of the email functions I've tried

```
function sendSimpleMail($to,$from,$subject,$message) {
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' ."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'To: '.$to ."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: '.$from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit'."\r\n";

    mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=',$message, $headers);
}
```

Any suggestions on alternative ways to achieve this goal?

Comment: I don't understand. What is the problem? you say the e-mail subject is correctly encoded... does it not work for the body as well?

Comment: Correct, the email subject can be shown correctly by using base64_encode, but you can't use base64_encode($email_content). See the example function above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, `8bit` encoding is not reliable in e-mail. Many mail transport agents will remove the top bit of every byte in the mail body. `بريد` is `"\xD8\xA8\xD8\xB1\xD9\x8A\xD8\xAF"` in UTF-8 bytes; remove the top bit from those bytes and you get ASCII `"X(X1Y\nX/"`.

The way to get non-ASCII characters into a mail body is to set `Content-Transfer-Encoding` to either `base64` or `quoted-printable`, and the encode the body with `base64_encode` or `quoted_printable_encode`, respectively.

(`quoted-printable` is better if the mail is largely ASCII as it retains readability in the encoded form and is more efficient for ASCII. If the whole mail is Arabic, `base64` would probably be the better choice.)

Comment: I modified the function to use base64_encode as Content-Transfer-Encoding: Base64 and OMG! it works!!! Hurray!

Comment: Why isn't 8 bit encoding reliable in Email? I sent UTF-8 encoded Hebrew emails regularly. Which MTA removes the top bit of every byte in the body?

Comment: TBH I don't know any more - sendmail didn't used to work but that was a long time ago. My gut suggests maybe mobile providers might still have some 7-bit transport kit and custom mail path handling lying about?

Comment: @bobince: I see, thanks. I take it then that email to a standard mail client on a desktop PC would be reliable, but some email-to-foobar technologies (such as SMS) might not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $boundary = uniqid(rand(), true);

        $headers  = "From: $from\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary = $boundary\n";
        $headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message.\n\n";
        $headers .= "--$boundary\n" .
                    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 \n" .
                    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n";
        $headers .= chunk_split(base64_encode($plaintext));
        $headers .= "--$boundary\n" .
                    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\n" .
                    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n";
        $headers .= chunk_split(base64_encode($msg));
        $headers .= "--$boundary--\n" .


        mail($address, $subject, '', $headers);
```

This one works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$headers .= 'From: =?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($from). "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me as-is.

Are you sure that `$message` contains a valid UTF-8 string?