# Problem Sending Mail through PHP

Tags: php

I have a contact form that is build in arabic language. When it is ever used, the received mail looks like this ...

```
Ø¥Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù…  Ø§Ù„Ø¥Ø³Ù…
Ù…Ù‡Ù†Ø¯Ø³ Ø¨Ø±Ù…Ø¬ÙŠØ§Øª   Ø§Ù„Ù…Ù‡Ù†Ø©
010 Ø§Ù„ØªÙ„ÙŠÙÙˆÙ†
email   Ø§Ù„Ø¨Ø±ÙŠØ¯ Ø§Ù„Ø¥Ù„ÙƒØªØ±ÙˆÙ†Ù‰
ØªØ¬Ø±Ø¨Ø©  Ø§Ù„Ø¥Ø³ØªÙØ³Ø§Ø±
```

I need to solve this issue as soon as possible as this page is a part of a company website that I`m updating.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I will try the methods on my localhost before using it on the website.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334935/how-do-i-send-emails-with-arabic-content-via-phps-mail-function

Comment: @Harmen: this didn`t work with me!!

Comment: USE PHPMAILER class is had function called `setCharset("utf-8")` , its your wanted help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure but the Lang attribute will used to display the language content

arabic language code is **ar**

Try this in your mail content

```
<P LANG=ar>This paragraph is in arabic.</P>
```

Comment: nope didn`t work. PS I tried it on localhost echo "اللغة العربية" . "<br>";
echo "<P LANG=ar>اللغة العربية</P>"; both produce Ø§Ù„Ù„ØºØ© Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø±Ø¨ÙŠØ©

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php 
echo "اللغة العربية";

?>
</body>
</html>

Comment: the php should come in between the body ... because <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />