# Font bug in mail function

Tags: php, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I send emails with Arabic content via PHP's mail function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334935/how-do-i-send-emails-with-arabic-content-via-phps-mail-function)

I am using function to send email but I have a problem if send the message in Arabic language !
the text will be like that :
`ãÑÍÈÇ \\r\\nßíÝß \\r\\nÃäÇ ÇÍãÏ`

```
function send_mail($to,$from,$title,$msg){
    /*
    function name : send_mail
     date          : 20.06.2009 09:38:29
    */

    $headers="from:$from";


    $subject=$title;

    if( mail($to,$subject,$msg,$headers) ){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }    
}
```

How to fix it ?

Comment: It looks like it'll be a character encoding issue, as you're not adding anything to the headers to identify the character set/encoding being used in the message.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334935/how-do-i-send-emails-with-arabic-content-via-phps-mail-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that may be a problem of content transfer

```
use base64_encode as Content-Transfer-Encoding: Base64 

$headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: Base64 '."\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the charset encoding in mail header to `UTF8`, rather I would prefer to use library [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)