# php html contact form with arabic message

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I'm working on contact form for my site, everything work good if i fill the inputs in English language but if i fill the inputs in arabic language i don't receive any emails, how i can fix this ?

this is my code :

HTML code :

```
<section class="body">

    <form action="form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <h1 class="title">Contact</h1>

        <label></label>
        <input name="d_name" required="required" placeholder="أسم المندوب">


        <label></label>
        <input name="d_phone" type="text" required="required" placeholder="رقم هاتف المندوب">


        <label></label>
        <input name="c_name" type="text" required="required" placeholder="أسم المشترك">

        <label></label> 
        <input name="phonee" required="required" type="text" placeholder="رقم هاتف المشترك" /> 


        <label></label>
        <select class="dropdown-select" name="comp" required="">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">أختر الشركة</option>
        <option value="جولان">جولان</option>
        <option value="بارتنير">بارتنير</option>
        <option value="بلفون">بلفون</option>
        <option value="تيلزار 019">تيلزار 019</option>
        </select>


        <label></label>
        <select name="type" required="">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">اختر نوع الرقم</option>
        <option value="فاتورة">فاتورة</option>
        <option value="كرت">كرت</option>
        </select>


        <label></label> 
        <input name="sim" required="required" type="text" placeholder="رقم الشريحة" /> 


        <label></label>
        <textarea name="message" cols="20" rows="5" required="required" placeholder="Message"></textarea>


        <input id="cancel" name="cancel" value="Cancel" />

        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>

</section>
```

PHP code :

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['d_name'];
$phone = $_POST['d_phone'];
$cname = $_POST['c_name'];
$cphone = $_POST['phonee'];
$comp = $_POST['comp'];
$sim = $_POST['sim'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From:' . $_POST['d_name']; 
$to = 'Noor_Phone@hotmail.com'; 
$subject = 'Email Inquiry';

$body = "Delegate Name: $name\n Delegate phone: $phone\n\n\n Customer Name: $cname\n Customer Phone: $cphone\n Line Type: $type\n Company: $comp\n Sim Number: $sim\n Message:\n $message";
 ?>

 <?php
if ($_POST['submit']) {
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    echo '<p>Thank you for your email!</p>';
} else { 
    echo '<p>Oops! An error occurred. Try sending your message again.     </p>'; 
 }
 }
?>
```

Comment: what gets output? Have you checked your spam box? Not much troubleshooting information given here

Comment: yes i checked everything , if i write  in english i received  the email, but if i write the form in arabic i don't received  anything.

Comment: So what does the php output in browser? You need to do some basic troubleshooting which we can't do for you

Comment: everything done right , and i have this when i submit the form "Thank you for your email!"
but i don't receive any email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for helping ,this is the answer:

HTML Code:

```
        <h1 class="title">Contact</h1>

        <label></label>
        <input name="d_name" required="required" placeholder="أسم المندوب">


        <label></label>
        <input name="d_phone" type="text" required="required" placeholder="رقم هاتف المندوب">


        <label></label>
        <input name="c_name" type="text" required="required" placeholder="أسم المشترك">

        <label></label> 
        <input name="phonee" required="required" type="text" placeholder="رقم هاتف المشترك" /> 


        <label></label>
        <select class="dropdown-select" name="comp" required="">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">أختر الشركة</option>
        <option value="جولان">جولان</option>
        <option value="بارتنير">بارتنير</option>
        <option value="بلفون">بلفون</option>
        <option value="تيلزار 019">تيلزار 019</option>
        </select>


        <label></label>
        <select name="type" required="">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">اختر نوع الرقم</option>
        <option value="فاتورة">فاتورة</option>
        <option value="كرت">كرت</option>
        </select>


        <label></label> 
        <input name="sim" required="required" type="text" placeholder="رقم الشريحة" /> 


        <label></label>
        <textarea name="message" cols="20" rows="5" required="required" placeholder="Message"></textarea>


        <input id="cancel" name="cancel" value="Cancel" />

        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>

</section>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$name = $_POST['d_name'];
$phone = $_POST['d_phone'];
$cname = $_POST['c_name'];
$cphone = $_POST['phonee'];
$comp = $_POST['comp'];
$sim = $_POST['sim'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="Delegate Name: $name\n Delegate phone: $phone\n\n\n      Customer Name: $cname\n Customer Phone: $cphone\n Line Type: $type\n   Company: $comp\n Sim Number: $sim\n Message:\n $message";
$recipient = "Noor_Phone@hotmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: admin@4uphone.co.il";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='contact.html' style='text-   decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Return Home</a>";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using php built-in mail function, use [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/). This will solve your problem. Using this class you have the option to set charset:

```
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```

For additional troubleshooting, you can

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

You also have the option to include charset attribute in the form tag:

```
<form action="form.php" method="post"
     enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

Or have a look at this old SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334935/how-do-i-send-emails-with-arabic-content-via-phps-mail-function) on sending arabic content in email.

Hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the Html Lang might help this situation try this

```
<html lang="ar">
```

Referenced from http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp