# how can make this function send Arabic format normally ? and what is the wron

Tags: php, email, php-5.6, mail-form, arabic-support

I want to make email function support Arabic

> ```
> <?php 
> if($nameFlag && $emailFlag && $messageFlag && $phoneFlag ) 
> {
>  if(!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($message) && !empty($phone))
>  {   
>
>     $recipient="yourMail";
>   $subject="Contact Form Messages";
>   $email=$_POST["email"];
>    $phone=$_POST["phone"];
>    $message=$_POST["message"];
>    $mailBody="Name: $name\nEmail: $email\nPhone: $phone \n\nMessage:$message";
>   mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$email>");
>   echo '<script type="text/javascript">
>                  alert("thanks for contacting , we will contacting you soon!") ;
>                  window.location.href = "YourSite";
>                </script>' ; 
>
>
>   }
>  }
>
>   ?>
> ```

i tried many code but they are didn't work

i coded it many times but i wondered why this problem appear now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I send emails with Arabic content via PHP's mail function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334935/how-do-i-send-emails-with-arabic-content-via-phps-mail-function)

Comment: i tried this code but it didn't work